# NAO or ROMEO aldebran robot in V-rep

Tags: ros, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I would like an opinion about the state of the art of 3D simulator.
I'm going to work with aldebaran robots NAO and ROMEO and I have to choose a simulation environment where to simulate those robots. The main candidates are:

1. Gazebo / MoveIt
2. V-rep
3. Webots

The real choice is between the first two simulators since they are completely open sources.
I would like an opinion from you about these two simulators and if there are existing models of the two robots above-mentioned.
In addition, I have to mention that I have to use those simulators also for motion planning (that I see this feature is included in V-rep while I have to use MoveIt for Gazebo).

I really appreciate if you give me an opinion with strength point / drawbacks of each of them from your experience.

Thanks in advance,

Neostek

P.S. Obviously, other simulators are welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54165/nao-or-romeo-aldebran-robot-in-v-rep/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

Since some time now, Aldebaran Robotics is delivering a SDK-simulator allowing you to connect with any simulator.

If you need more information, I'll be happy to help.

Best,

---

Originally posted by [cleblanc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4214/cleblanc/) with karma: 16 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know very well these simulators, as far as we are concerned, HRP-2 users, we are working with the [OpenHRP simulator](http://www.openrtp.jp/openhrp3/en/index.html). This is mainly due to the high fidelity of the dynamics simulation. This is the most crucial part when it comes to human-size humanoid robots. This is crucial for us as these robots are big, costly and powerful.

If you plan on working on control algorithms for humanoid robots then you should first review if other people doing humanoid robotics are using it and how good is the result. Then comes all the other features (ROS integration, sensor simulation, ease of use). The community also is a major factor.

The fact that it is bundled with Nao/Romeo should not be a major criteria for your decision, it is not that hard to port a model from one system to another (or even patching an open-source project to load a new file format is not that difficult either).

Long story short, because of the community size, the fact it is used in the Darpa Challenge ([see here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install)) and its nice ROS features among these three simulators I would choose Gazebo. You may also want to consider OpenHRP.

NB: Another nice robotics simulator is [MORSE](http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/). Unfortunately it is not focused on humanoid robots.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-02-21**:
Just adding an fyi, `OpenHRP3` binary package is now available via ROS repository too (you may expect more frequent updates than its original repo): http://wiki.ros.org/openhrp3